Symfony 5.4 BotMan Chatbot, function not working
This my BotManController, i don't know why it is not getting functions mostly I think the error is in my controller not being able to get the botman method.
class BotManController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/botman', name: 'botman', methods: ['GET', 'POST'])]
    public function messageAction(Request $request): Response
    {

        DriverManager::loadDriver(\BotMan\Drivers\Web\WebDriver::class);

        $config = [
            'web' => [
            'matchingData' => [
            'driver' => 'web',],
            ],
        ];
    $adapter = new FilesystemAdapter();
        $botman = BotManFactory::create($config, new SymfonyCache($adapter));

        $botman->hears('hi', function (BotMan $bot,) {
            $bot->reply('Hello yourself.');
        });
        
        // Start listening
        $botman->listen();

        // Return a response (optional)
        return new Response();
        
    }

#[Route('/chatframe', name: 'chatframe')]
    public function chatframeAction(): Response
    {
        // Your controller logic goes here
        return $this->render('bot_man/chatframe.html.twig');
    }

}

This is my Screenshot on other codes, the first one is the testing, the second one is widget homepage code and the chatframe code. My debugging on controller, there is no error showing, thats about it. I really have no idea why it is not reponsing or maybe im just stupid. Im new to Symfony and I'm using 5.4 with basic requirements.
I cannot ss anymore i dont know why its telling me there is to much code.

Do you have any specific question about this code?

My chatbot is not getting response, in
$botman->hears('hi', function (BotMan $bot) {
$bot->reply('Hello yourself.');
});
I type Hi, there is no response, help

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Also, share your debugging attempts

I updated it, I use stackoverflow only for searching for related problems and this is my first time. Is there anyway i can send screenshot?

No, there's no need to share a screenshot. Share all details in text form
